# Destroy Function on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, flexslider

I have a page in my project that contains several categories and each category has a Flexslider with images. Each category is displayed once and clicking another, the former is hidden and clicked appears, similar scheme with Tabs.

I need that when I click on another category, it destroys the function of Flexslider initialised in the former category and is executed in this category.

Here's what I've done so far, without success:

Function that starts Flexslider:

```
vm.sliderCol = function () {

    setTimeout(function () {

        $('.sliderCol').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false
        })
    }, 1000)
}
```

Function that enter the category button:

```
vm.clicou = function(){

    $('.sliderCol').flexslider("destroy")

    setTimeout(function () {
        vm.sliderCol()
    }, 1000)
}
```

Until then I tried to destroy the Flexslider do not know if there is some method to stop performing the function and start it, can anyone help?

Comment: This might helps your 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ng-click on each category playing the role, I managed to destroy the slider and start it again with the following function:

```
vm.clicou = function(){
    $('.sliderCol').flexslider("destroy");
    $('.sliderCol').removeData("flexslider");
    setTimeout(function () {
        vm.sliderCol();
    }, 100);
}
```